# What is the relationship between a container and block size/input split?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am new to Hadoop. I wanted to know if there is a relationship between a container and block size/input split?

I think there is some relationship b/w the two as I read that Container signifies an allocated resources on the Node Manager where the computation happens, but doesn't computation happens per input splits?